# Issue with UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

rp_format

```
+-----+--+--------------+
| fid |  | recordformat |
+-----+--+--------------+
|   1 |  | CD           |
|   2 |  | Vinyl        |
|   3 |  | DVD          |
+-----+--+--------------+
```

rp_records

```
+----+--+--------+
| id |  | format |
+----+--+--------+
|  1 |  |      1 |
|  2 |  |      2 |
|  3 |  |      3 |
+----+--+--------+
```

What I would like to achieve is to display everything from "rp_format". But I would also like make a check to see if there is a "fid"-value found in "format".

Example that should be displayed on page like this:

```
fid         recordformat
1           CD              Remove this format
2           Vinyl           Remove this format
3           DVD             Remove this format
```

But let's say an "fid" value is found in "format" then I would like it to be displayed like this on page:

```
fid         recordformat
1           CD              Remove this format
2           Vinyl           Can't remove this format
3           DVD             Remove this format
```

"Remove this format / Can't remove this format" is text that will be displayed by checking if "fid" = "format" using PHP.

Here is my SQL query so far:

```
global $wpdb;
$rpdb = $wpdb->prefix . 'rp_format';
$rpdb2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'rp_records';

$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM $rpdb
LEFT OUTER JOIN $rpdb2 ON $rpdb.fid = $rpdb2.format

UNION

SELECT *
FROM $rpdb
RIGHT OUTER JOIN $rpdb2 ON $rpdb.fid = $rpdb2.format
WHERE $rpdb.fid IS NOT NULL
";
```

The issue I have with this query is that when "fid" is found in "format" (let's say it's found 10 times) every of these 10 values will be outputed also.

How can this be fixed?

Kind regards
Johan

Comment: Could you update your question with the complete tables please? This is important for answering. You can use [this](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: Better @marijnz0r? :)

Comment: Not clear , if the `rp_format.fid` is found on  `rp_records.format` then it should display `Can't remove this format` else `Remove this format` is this what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes @AbhikChakraborty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to display some message depending on if the data exists on `rp_records` or not and avoid multiple display.

Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from rp_format;
+------+--------------+
| fid  | recordformat |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | CD           |
|    2 | Vinyl        |
|    3 | DVD          |
|    4 | Test         |
+------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from rp_records;
+------+--------+
| id   | format |
+------+--------+
|    1 |      1 |
|    2 |      2 |
|    3 |      3 |
|    4 |      2 |
|    5 |      1 |
+------+--------+
```

So the query is

```
select 
f.*, 
case  
  when r.format is not null then 'Can\'t remove' else 'Remove this' end 
as message 
from rp_format f 
left join rp_records r on r.format = f.fid 
group by f.fid  ;


+------+--------------+--------------+
| fid  | recordformat | message      |
+------+--------------+--------------+
|    1 | CD           | Can't remove |
|    2 | Vinyl        | Can't remove |
|    3 | DVD          | Can't remove |
|    4 | Test         | Remove this  |
+------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if this way is the best solution, but I can still use it and make it work for my intentions. :D I replaced the texts with "1" and "2" and with PHP doing like this:  if ($result->message == "1") { //do something } else { //do something else }. So in a way it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that i correctly understand your logic with found and not found format, if i wrong - add to if condition `r.format IS NOT NULL` instead `r.format IS NULL`. And i think you no need to use **union**, you should use **join**:

```
SELECT
    r.fid,
    f.recordformat,
    IF(r.format IS NULL, "Can't remove this format", "Remove this format")
FROM rp_format f
LEFT JOIN rp_records r ON f.fid = r.format
GROUP BY f.fid
;
```

I'm sure that something like this will help you!